# Overwriting a function on window

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My understanding was that if you overwrote a function on the window object it would be forever overwritten during that session.

However, I recently tried overwriting `window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` but found that other source's `watchPosition` function where unchanged.

Here's a list of sources

1. Main website bundle
2. Extension on website
3. Snippet inside of google chrome dev tools

These all had different readings on the `window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` despite being inside of the same window.

Example code

```
window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition = function(success, error, options){
            success({ coords: { 
              latitude: 15.0, 
              longitude: 15.0,
          }, timestamp: Date.now() }); 
        }
```

All three sources will list different lat/lon if you change the variables for them.

Can somebody explain to me if it's possible to overwrite functions on the window object for all other sources? Or am I already doing this right and possibly messing up somewhere else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Browser extensions use a different environment than the webpage. Also when did you overwrite the method? If it wasnt before other code already called it and set up their callbacks changing that method wouldnt affect them.

Comment: @PatrickEvans ohhh, I didn't know that. Currently the browser extension is set to run at `document_start`. Is it possible to target the webpage environment window via the extension?

Comment: @PatrickEvans the scripts are added via `content_scripts` but it seems like the environment is still different. Could it be possible that the webpage has its own environment? it is a webpack app.

Comment: Sorry yea they are still in separate environments but they do share the same DOM. So you need to manually add your script to the page DOM from the content script to get to the same space. Eg create new script element, set its textContent to the code you want run then add it to page [sample code here](https://pastebin.com/raw/ajgvtAvk)

Comment: @PatrickEvans fantastic, thank you so much. I'll try this first thing in the morning

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hey Patrick, can you put your comment as an answer please? It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts have their own isolated environment. Meaning they do not share functions, variables etc. This means changing an object in the content script isnt going to be observable to the actual page. This is why there are differences from your script from your extension and code included in the on the page and in the console. Note though you can change the dev tools console to work in the extension environment, simply select it from the drop down menu in the tab.

Both content script and page do however have access to the same page DOM. So either can add/remove elements to the page. This allows a content script to add a script to the page which runs in the same environment as the regular scripts on the page.

```
//inside content script
let s=document.createElement('script')
s.textContent = 'your code here';
//or use getURL() to get a usable url to set
//src to
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('scriptforpage.js')
document.head.appendChild(s)
```